# JLPT N3 task explanation

Tags: jlpt

I have been solving the grammar tasks for JLPT N3. I have made a mistake in the following question.

> お金をいただいてからでないと、商品はお渡し（  　　  ）。
>
> ーします
> ーできます
> ーなりません
> ーできません

I know the right answer is できません, but I still don't understand why. Can you explain to me please why other answers are wrong? It just seems to me that there is not enough context to solve this task.

I can guess that the first part translates like:
If after I get money, it doesn't come off, the delivery of the item is...
But I can't guess the right answer only from this. Can you help me please to understand it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

your confusion stems from the fact that you are mis-translating でない as "can't come off". However this is actually a portion of a standard sentence fragment:

> てからでないと

which is a phrase meaning "something can't happen until something else happens first"  (here is a link that might help: https://japanesetest4you.com/flashcard/learn-jlpt-n2-grammar-%E3%81%A6%E3%81%8B%E3%82%89%E3%81%A7%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84%E3%81%A8-tekara-denai-to/

so this sentence, with できません correctly attached, translates to

> Until/Unless I/we receive the money I/we cannot deliver the goods.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation. I completely understand now. It just didn't occur to me it was some standard phrase since I have never seen it before. Thank you